# Weird glitching after using solidify

Tags: modeling

I was following some basic tutorial on youtube to make basic levels and after I used the solidify modifier to make the walls thicker, this weird glitching happened in the corners. Can you explain to my why and what should I do to avoid it? Thanks.

[image]

[image: Corner messed up]

Comment: Would help if we could see your  .bled file. You can upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  . Then Edit your question and paste in the new URL.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog I've been trying to upload it on your website and nothing is happening. Do you have a better website where I could upload my file?

Comment: you need to put the address of this page in the field where it's asked to be able to upload. If you still don't succeed use a site like wetransfer

Comment: The file is in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove Doubles from your mesh for the solidify modifier to work correctly.
Open the Specials menu and choose **Remove Doubles**.

[image]

Then enable **Backface Culling** and you will see that your mesh is "inside out ". 
Correct this by selecting all then open the **Specials** menu again and this time choose **Flip Normals**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapped vertices in corners.

1. Go to *Edit* mode.
2. Select all vertices by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. In *Vertex* mode press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type "Remove Doubles".